# NameError: name 'mean' is not defined

Tags: python

Calculating the basic statistics, I get the following working well:

```
import pandas as pd    

max(df[Price]) 
min(df[Price])
```

But, this is returning an error:

```
mean(df[Price]) 

NameError: name 'mean' is not defined
```

I'm just trying to understand the logic of this.

This one works well:

```
df[Price].mean()
```

What kind of statistics work after the dot and which ones must wrap the column?

Comment: It's not a good idea to try and understand it as "after the dot" and "wrap the column". You may want to read a Python tutorial to understand what these two actually are (a method call and a function call, respectively).

Comment: @AKX sure, thanks a lot. I've read many, maybe that's the problem. Although it is clear the difference between a method and a function, from a statistician perspective it just doesn't make sense

Comment: `min` and `max` are functions which python provides by default. There is no default `mean` function, so when you try `mean(df[Price])` python tries to find any user defined function named `mean` and raises the `NameError` when it could not find any function named `mean`. The `df[Price].mean()` is the function provided by the `Pandas` library. Refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html)

Comment: Put `from statistics import mean` at the top of your script and you'll get a `mean` function that takes an iterable as its argument, similar to the builtin `max` and `min` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#min) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#max) are functions provided as Python built-ins.

You can use them on any iterable, which includes Pandas series, which is why what you're doing works.

Pandas also provides [`.min()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html#pandas.Series.min) and [`.max()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html#pandas.Series.max) as methods on series and dataframes, so e.g. `df["Price"].min()` would *also* work. The full list of Series functions is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html); the full list of DataFrame functions is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html).

If you do want to use a free function called `mean()`, e.g. when you have something that's not a Pandas series and you don't want to convert it to one, one actually [does exist in the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean), but you will have to import it:

```
from statistics import mean
```

Comment: Ok, in order to have the code consistent, then perhaps I should always import pandas and always refer to the methods and forget the functions.

Comment: If you're working with Pandas objects, then yes, it's probably better (and likely faster too) to use the methods when you can.