# How to hide Log info in Pycaret using Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pycaret

I would like to hide the log info below when I run any code in Pycaret using Google Colab.

```
compare_models()
```

[image]

I've tried passing the parameter `verbose = False`, but no difference.

I've also tried:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.CRITICAL)
```

But no difference.

Comment: Is the log info going to `sys.stdout` ? (Or stderr?) Can you redirect that? Also, isn't there a configured [logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) for which you could `setLevel()` to debug instead of info? [Let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) what solution you settle upon.

Comment: Actually, I don't know. Where can I find where the log info is going to?

Comment: Refer to the cited logger documentation to track down how logging is configured in your particular project. Consider defining a _new_ logger that logs to a file -- that will help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank, I guess this is not related with python but with Google colab?

Comment: No, it should work the same when run within Terminal.app or within colab. You might start by changing the config of [DashboardLogger](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/pycaret/loggers/dashboard_logger.py). All through the code we see a common idiom of `LOGGER = get_logger()` (from the internal.logging module). That should give you a handle on how to `.setLevel()` to your desired verbosity, or how to silently redirect all of a logger's output to a file. You must read the builtin [logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) docs to solve this.

Comment: OK, thanks for the links to the docs

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your notebook.

```
import os
os.environ["PYCARET_CUSTOM_LOGGING_LEVEL"] = "CRITICAL"
```

More info can be found in this GitHub Issue: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/2440